# Ansible get specified --key-file in task

Tags: ansible

I'm specifying the custom ssh key file with the following command:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory.cfg --key-file ssh_keyfile
```

Now I want to add the same key to the host I'm managing with Ansible with the following task:

```
- name: add ssh key
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ user }}"
    state: present
    key: "{{ lookup('file', ssh_keyfile) }}"
```

How can I get the value of the `--key-file` specified in command line when running playbook, as a variable inside the playbook?

Comment: Is the above code giving you an error

Comment: @Ash I've replaced an actual path (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) with `ssh_keyfile` string, now it's used twice, which I don't like.

Comment: But it doesn't give any errors now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The --key-file ssh_keyfile is a private key file path which will be used to authenticate to the remote server.

Ansible `authorized_key` module will look for public key so you have to use lookup for that